# 2 domains, 1 site, url rewrite from non-www to www with https

Tags: asp.net, https, url-rewriting

I have an application I wrote in ASP.NET C#.   Two domains point to the site.
In the web.config I'd like a url rewrite so if   http://domain.com is entered it redirects to https://www.domain.com

In addition if http://domain2.com is entered it should redirect to https://www.domain2.com

I see a bunch of examples when its just one domain.   Wondering if its possible when 2 domains point to the same site.  When I tried I got redirect loops.

Comment: Can you just create a 2nd web site with bindings for the 2nd domain and do the regular redirect there?

Comment: No, because i want to manage one piece of source in one directory.

So the site would be in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\

and I want www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com to point to the same directory...using https as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<rule name="NON-WWW HTTPS DOMAIN" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to domain HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[www\.]*domain\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to domain2 HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[www\.]*domain2\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="NON-WWW HTTPS DOMAIN 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain2\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

In order to redirect https://domain.com or https://domain2.com to https://www.domain.com and https://www.domain2.com you need to enable https for: domain.com/www.domain.com and domain2.com/www.domain2.com. It must be enabled in IIS because otherwise IIS will block request for not binded https request and the request will not even be processed by rewrite url.

Comment: This is pretty darn close.   Works for www.domain2.com and www.domain1.com    if I enter   domain2.com or domain1.com i get a 404 error.   Can I add a rule to include www if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work..get a page not found error.

Comment: @VibrationOfLife ok, now should be ok.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions...unfortunately that doesn't work either.  Same 404 error using http://domain1.com    http://domain2.com    oddly enough  https://domain1.com  says the certificates don't match...instead of 404.

Comment: @VibrationOfLife Hmm, I tried it locally and it works. Can you provide a sample full url you are trying? And are you sure these are the only rules you have in web.config?

Comment: Do you try this non-www url with https prefix? I mean domain.com and domain2.com? Do you test it with http or https?

Comment: I got pulled off this project task for the day..i'll pick it up tomorrow.  our SSL certificate is only configured for www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com    so entering non-www I want to redirect.   I tested both ways...https://www  and http://www   works fine....its the https:// or http:// w/o the www that doesn't....thanks for helping i really appreciate it.

Comment: @VibrationOfLife Ok so I've recreated your environment. I've created website and add 2 domain to it. Then I've created http/https mappings and  it works like you want.

Comment: for anyone else you can remove /Test from his solution....   make sure your IIS bindings are set correclty.

Comment: Ah, y :) That was my test suite, forgot to remove before posting my answer.